# Provider 'gridServiceApi' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to get a factory to work in an AngularJS app I'm working on. The following is my dumbed down factory code:

```
angular.module('workhelpr.components.services.gridService', [])
.factory('gridServiceApi', function () {
  return { test:5 };
});
```

When I inject this factory into a controller as follows:

```
mainCtrl.$inject = ['gridServiceApi'];
function mainCtrl(gridServiceApi) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  //gridServiceApi.test();

}
```

I get the following error in the browser console:

```
angular.js:13550 Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'gridServiceApi' must return a value from $get factory method.
```

I have googled the hell out of this and there are a bunch of questions asked which are very similar. Most of them were problems where the factory did not return an object or the intended return value was on a line below the return keyword. I haven't found anything that actually answers why this is happening here.

Comment: What happen when you set the factory like `.factory('gridServiceApi', function () {
  return { test: function() { return 5;} };
});` and use it like in your controller (`gridServiceApi.test();`)

Comment: It returns exactly the same error.

Comment: I have edited the basic example of `controllerAs` from angularjs documentation, and added the factory as you did (https://plnkr.co/edit/30swPWudsuDfKgmuVsI5?p=preview) It work like a charm. Are you sure you're referencing to the factory inside `workhelpr.components.services.gridService` and that it's not another factory with the same name that exist in another module? - Have you included `workhelpr.components.services.gridService` module in your app module?

Comment: Turns out My path to the service .js file was wrong. Which is odd, I would have expected it to throw an unknown injector error in this case which is Why I wasn't looking for that. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's why a asked about it, because if i'm using a name of a factory that doesn't exist it gives another error. My wild guess was that another factory/service with the same name was found in one of the other modules.

Comment: No. I know for a fact that there was no factory/service by the same name. Since this app (so far) only consists of 1 directive, and this service. No possibility for name duplication. It was an incorrect path.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the path to my service.js file was incorrect. Which was confusing as I would have expected it to throw an unknown provider error.